# Set default ResultSet Type to TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE in Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, jdbc

From what I can see Spring JDBC sets the default ResultSet type to `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` in `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory`. I'd like to change it so all my Spring DAOs get `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` for all queries.

Is the best approach to simply extend `PreparedStatementCreatorFactory` with the new default, and then have all my DAOs use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but just in case someone gets into the same issue and lands here.

The way I solved this problem is simply by extending the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Example

```
public class ScrollNamedParameterJdbcTemplate extends NamedParameterJdbcTemplate {

  public ScrollNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  protected PreparedStatementCreatorFactory getPreparedStatementCreatorFactory(
      ParsedSql parsedSql, SqlParameterSource paramSource) {
    String sqlToUse = NamedParameterUtils.substituteNamedParameters(parsedSql, paramSource);
    List<SqlParameter> declaredParameters =
        NamedParameterUtils.buildSqlParameterList(parsedSql, paramSource);
    PreparedStatementCreatorFactory preparedStatementCreatorFactory =
        new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sqlToUse, declaredParameters);
    preparedStatementCreatorFactory.setResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
    return preparedStatementCreatorFactory;
  }
}
```

Then create a bean definition for this specific template

```
@Bean("scrollNamedParameterJdbcTemplate")
  NamedParameterJdbcOperations scrollNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new ScrollNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }
```

Then you can just inject this template if you need the scroll type on your result sets